# How to wire a ceiling fan with a red, black, white, ground in ceiling box?

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I need help wiring a ceiling fan with a red, black, white, ground in ceiling box to a remote receiver with black and white to a black, white, and blue to fan with black, white, blue, ground.

Single wall switch with black and red connected at the moment.

I cannot get the wall switch to control any part of the fan or light functions. Remote does everything.

Comment: What model is your remote/receiver? Are you wedded to it, or are you OK with considering other options for a remote control?  What do you want the wall switch to control?

Answer (score 2):

Connect the remote receiver to the fan wiring: black to black, blue to blue, white to white.

Connect the supply wires to the remote receiver: black to black, white to white.

Connect the grounds together: green (supply) to green (fan), along with a pigtail to the junction box if it's metal.

Cap off the red wire in the ceiling.

Remove the red wire from the switch and cap it off.

If you wanted the switch to control the fan or lights directly, connect the supply black to the black (fan) or blue (lights) from the fan, not the remote receiver. Cap off the corresponding wire from the remote receiver. Given that you only have 1 switch on the wall, though, it's probably best to control everything via the remote. Also keep in mind that if you connect the fan this way, you lose the ability to adjust the speed.

Answer (score 0):

So that the switch still operates the light, <and don't have to enter a dark room to find the remote>, wire the red wire directly to the 2 blue wires, bypassing the controller. Can turn on the light with the switch, with the switch in the off position, remote operates light and switch normally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is there to add? This is what I figured out when there were no examples or explanations to follow.